# Prove that $\cos 2x + \cos 2y + \cos 2z = -4(\cos x \cos y \cos z) -1$ when $x+y+z=\pi$

Tags: trigonometry

I found on [List of trigonometric identities on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) that $\cos 2x + \cos 2y + \cos 2z = -4(\cos x \cos y \cos z) -1$ if $x+y+z=\pi = 180°$. I couldn't find a proof.

Comment: Can we use complex numbers ?

Comment: preferably not, but I will accept the answer if I don't get a better one

Comment: Ok so here is a proof with complex numbers: Using that $\cos(\pi -x)=-\cos(x)$ and $\cos(2\pi-x)=\cos(x)$, our statement is equivalent to $$\cos(2x)+\cos(2y)+\cos(2(x+y))=4 \cos(x) \cos(y) \cos(x+y)-1$$ By Euler, $\cos(x)=\Re(\exp(i x))$ so expansion shows that both sides are equal to $$\frac{1}{2} e^{-2 i x-2 i y}+\frac{1}{2} e^{2 i x+2 i y}+\frac{1}{2} e^{-2 i
   x}+\frac{1}{2} e^{2 i x}+\frac{1}{2} e^{-2 i y}+\frac{1}{2} e^{2 i y}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\cos2z=\cos2(\pi-x-y)=\cos2(x+y)=2\cos^2(x+y)-1$. Then use the sum-to-product identity twice:
$$\begin{align}
\cos2x+\cos2y+\cos2z&=2\cos(x+y)\cos(x-y)+2\cos^2(x+y)-1 \\
&=2\cos(x+y)\bigl(\cos(x-y)+\cos(x+y)\bigr)-1 \\
&=4\cos(x+y)\cos x\cos y-1 \\
&=4\cos(\pi-z)\cos x\cos y-1 \\
&=-4\cos z\cos x\cos y-1 \\
&=-4\cos x\cos y\cos z-1
\end{align}$$

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 0):

$$
\text{LHS}{=\cos 2x+\cos 2y+\cos (2x+2y)
\\=\cos 2x+\cos 2y+\cos 2x\cos 2y-\sin 2x\sin 2y
}
$$
$$
\text{RHS}{=4\cos x\cos y\cos(x+y)-1
\\=4\cos^2 x\cos^2 y-4\cos x\cos y\sin x\sin y-1
\\=(\cos 2x+1)(\cos 2y+1)-\sin 2x\sin 2y-1
\\=\cos 2x+\cos 2y+\cos 2x\cos 2y-\sin 2x\sin 2y
}
$$
which completes the proof $\blacksquare$